# How to solve docker-entrypoint.sh executable file not found in $PATH: unknown?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm having trouble while trying to start the backend for my application on Docker. I get the following error when I select Compose Up on VS Code. I read that I need to add `RUN chmod -x docker-entrypoint.sh` on my Dockerfile, but it didn't solved the problem.

```
Successfully built some_id_abc123
mongodb is up-to-date
cache is up-to-date
Recreating some_project_server ... error

ERROR: for some_project_server Cannot start service server: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "docker-entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

ERROR: for server  Cannot start service server: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "docker-entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
The terminal process "/bin/zsh '-c', 'docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" up -d --build'" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run dev
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  database:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=some_db
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=some_user
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_password
    volumes:
      - ./mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
      - ./mongo-volume:/data/db
    networks:
      - server-network

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: cache
    command: redis-server --requirepass some_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./redis-data:/var/lib/redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    networks:
      - server-network

  server:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
    environment:
      - ENV_VARIABLES=some_env_variables
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app
    networks:
      - server-network

networks:
  server-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Finally, here's the file structure of the project:

```
project
  - src
  - test
  - .dockerignore
  - docker-compose.yml
  - Dockerfile
  - mongo-init.js
  - package-lock.json
  - package.json
```

What is this problem's origin and how to solve it? I'm starting with Docker and this is my first professional project I'm working that Docker is necessary.

Comment: Why are you doing `RUN chmod -x docker-entrypoint.sh` instead of `RUN chmod +x ...`? And how are you running `docker-entrypoint.sh`? Where did you add or copy it?

Comment: Actually I tried but removed this command, I read on other posts that when this problem occurred, this was the solution, so I created a docker-entrypoint.sh with `exec npm run dev` something like that, just to see if this would solve the problem, but nope, didn't helped either, so I removed the file and the command. @Saeed

Comment: Can you try `ENTRYPOINT["npm","run","dev"]` instead of `CMD`

Comment: This causes the following error @MustafaGüler `starting container process caused: exec: "npm": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

Comment: At some point, did you have `image: node` in your `docker-compose.yml`?  If you `docker rmi node` and then re-run `docker-compose up -d --build`, is it any better (Docker will pull the upstream `node` image again)?

Comment: I do not see `docker-entrypoint.sh` in your `Dockerfile` and I've not got my answers. But I'll write the answer based on some assumptions. If needed, comment below my answer.

Comment: There’s no `docker-entrypoint.sh` in my `Dockerfile` or my project, this is one of the questions I have, because if there isn’t one, why the problem is in this specific file? I think I wasn’t clear with my answer, I tried creating this `docker-entrypoint.sh` file with `!#/bin/bash exec npm run dev` at the root and then ran the command you said, but it didn’t solved the problem, so I deleted it @Saeed

Comment: @DavidMaze yep and I tried this command, I also removed all containers and images, so Docker downloaded all three images again and tried to rebuild them all, Mongo and Redis worked just fine, but Node continued to show the error message. I really don't know what's going on, probably it's something silly that I'm not seeing hahah

Answer (score 0):

Try
`docker compose build`
and next
`docker compose up`
Found it [HERE](https://fantashit.com/error-when-trying-to-run-docker-compose-up-oci-runtime-error-container-linux-go-247/)
Worked for me.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29953168)